# Can I submit the next paper before a previous base paper gets published?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, patents

I wanted to publish an algorithm in a journal and submitted the paper to be published within the next 6-months. Meanwhile, before the publication of the submitted paper, I optimized the algorithm.

Can I submit and publish the optimized algorithm before the previous base algorithm is published?

Comment: Was the first paper accepted for publication or is it still in review?

Comment: The base paper is still in review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in general you can do this. It is best if the first paper is already accepted but not essential.

Note that the publication process takes a while, so that it is possible to update citations. The final paper published is almost never the one first submitted.

The only difference is how you cite the first paper in the second for purposes of the submission. For a paper that has been accepted, you cite it as "to be published" or "to appear". For one that is under review, list it that way: "under review".

It is also best if the journals for the paper are one and the same. Just let the editor know that you are citing a paper that they are reviewing. This will aid them in reviewer selection.

The citations will work themselves out in the end, even if the editor's advice is to combine the papers and submit the result as a single paper.

Comment: Thankyou!  Can I submit in the case of the optimized algorithm is sent for the patent filing instead of a journal before the base algorithm is get published ?

Comment: They are somewhat separate, but filing a patent earliest is a good idea. In some places more than others. Keeping information private prior to patent filing is best.